# I am getting errors while adding google job posting (indexing api)

Tags: php, google-api, google-indexing-api

I would be really happy to get a solution for this. 
This is the error:

> { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Permission denied. Failed to
>   verify the URL ownership.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

As I have followed all the steps given in the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart).

I have verified the url ownership and added service account as owner. Here is the code snippet. Please check and reply with a solution, if you have.

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__)."/google-api-php-client_1/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(dirname(__FILE__).'/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';
$array= array("url"=>"https://www.mycoders.in/career","type"=>"URL_UPDATED");
$content= json_encode($array);
$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$response2 = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Thanks in advance!
Rohit

Comment: I got the solution myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably your service account is set to "Full" instead of Owner. If that is the case, you have to change your account to Owner. Use the [Old Webmasters tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home) to do that.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4763732?hl=en

Comment: This answer helped solve my proble! Thanks @rodrigo